# copying the character pointer has no effect once out of function, expected garbage value, but restores the previous address

Tags: c

I am writing the a very simple string reversing function,

```
void reverse(char *data) {
    int length = 0,i;   
    char *temp,temp1[100];
    temp = data;
    length = strlen(temp);
    printf("length %d\n", length);
    for(i=length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        temp1[i] = *temp;
        printf("data[%d] = %c\n",i,temp1[i]);
        printf("%c\n",*temp);
        temp++;
    }
    temp1[length] = '\0';
    printf("data %s\n", temp1);
    //strcpy(data,temp1); // works even outside this function, offcourse it must
    data = temp1;   //works inside this function, but not outside this function
    printf("data %s\n", data);
}

int main()
{   
    int length1 = 0;
    char data1[100] = "I am megharaj from india";
    printf("data1 %s\n", data1);
    reverse(data1);
    printf("reversed\n");
    printf("data1 %s\n", data1);    
    return 0;
}
```

data = temp1; this works in reverse function, but does not work in main function.
yes, that is default so once it comes outside the function it will not be present on stack, but why in the main function data1 prints the string "I am megharaj from india", I was expecting it to print garbage value
because something i have allocated and thats no more present, so it must print garbage value.Why does it retain its previous address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp` is a copy of the contents of `data` placed on stack locally in your `reverse` function. In the strictest sense of the word, everything in C is pass-by-value. When we pass-by-value we are passing a copy of the variable to a function. **It is copying the value of the array's address**, into the function.

> data = temp1; this works in reverse function, but does not work in main function. yes, that is default so once it comes outside the function it will not be present on stack

That is not the only reason, `temp1` is a local array in reverse, you cannot access it outside your `reverse` function (since it is not global to be visible in `reverse`).

So there are 2 arrays

```
 +---+---+---+---+--+---+---+
 | I am megharaj from india |
 +---+---+---+---+--+---+---+ data1 in main
```

The above gets destroyed after execution of `main`.

```
 +---+---+---+---+--+---+---+
 | I am megharaj from india |
 +---+---+---+---+--+---+---+ temp1 in reverse
```

The above gets destroyed after execution of `reverse`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 arrays, `Data1` and `Temp1`. and two pointers `Data` and `Temp`.
Initially after entering the function, both `Data` and `Temp` points to the first element of `Data1`.
Then you fill up `Temp1` using `Temp` as an index.
Then you put `Data` to point to `Temp1`.
Now, if you print `Data`, you are actually printing the elements of `Temp1`, So you see the reversed string.
**Notice, `Data1` is never changed in this process.**
When you come out of the function, `Data`, `Temp` and `Temp1` does not exist as they are out of scope. **But `Data1` still exist as its scope is function main()**.
**After returning from the function, you are printing `Data1`, that is still holding initial values you set, it is never changed or destroyed**. That's why, you don't see garbage value.

Comment: `Notice, Data1 is never changed in this process.` - I think the OP is clear about `Data1` not getting modified - he is unsure of the fact that the reference to `Data1` is not destroyed.

Comment: I mentioned `When you come out of the function, Data, Temp and Temp1 does not exist` and `After returning from the function, you are printing Data1, that is still holding initial values you set, it is never changed or destroyed. That's why, you don't see garbage value.` though.

Answer (score 0):

`temp1`, `data1` are two arrays.

`temp`, `data` are just two pointers.

When you call the function `reverse(data1);`

`the pointer data starts to point the array data1.`

After completing your reverse core operations you are doing

`data = temp1;`

Where your pointer data leaves array data1, and starts pointing temp1.

When you do `printf("data %s\n", data);` means you are printing contents of temp1 array using the pointer data.  AND THIS DOES NOT MEAN THAT THE CONTENTS OF THE ARRAY `data1` ARE CHANGED.

So after leaving the function, as the contents of `data1` NOT CHANGED they will print as well.